# Initially I want ON button to be display block and off to display none, if I click ON button, OFF appears & On disappears, and vice versa

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to achieve a toggle effect using display properties, only one button should be on display at a time, while the other is hidden and vice versa. Currently, I am able to hide the off button if I click any of the buttons, so what do I do to get only one displayed at a time

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("on");
  var y = document.getElementById("off");
  
  y.style.display ="none";

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } 
  else {
    y.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="on">ON</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="off">OFF</button>
```

Comment: Instead of showing both the buttons at a time .. you can set one button display as none and then play on click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your logic is that you need to switch the `display` state of both elements within the function you call:

```js
var on = document.getElementById("on");
var off = document.getElementById("off");
  
function myFunction() {  
  if (on.style.display === "none") {  
    off.style.display = "none";
    on.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    off.style.display = "block";
    on.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="on">ON</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="off" style="display: none;">OFF</button>
```

Another way to do what you require would be to use a CSS class to hide the required element. This avoids the need for the `if` condition. You can then use `classList.toggle()` to switch the class on/off on each element on successive clicks. Something like this:

```js
let toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle');

toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', e => {
    toggles.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('hide'));
  });
});
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<button class="toggle" id="on">ON</button>
<button class="toggle hide" id="off">OFF</button>
```

Or even more simply using jQuery:

```js
let $toggles = $('.toggle').on('click', () => $toggles.toggleClass('hide'));
```

```css
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggle" id="on">ON</button>
<button class="toggle hide" id="off">OFF</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, second option worked for me, I am still a newbie finding my way around, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, when the on and off buttons are clicked, the `toggle()` method is called and the `display` properties are changed. In order to hide a button initially, I set the `display` property of the `<button>` with an `off` id value to `none`; this feature can also be provided by using the `onload` event that is triggered when the page is loaded.

```js
const on = document.getElementById('on');
const off = document.getElementById('off');

function toggle(){
  if(on.style.display === 'none'){
    on.style.display = 'block';
    off.style.display = 'none';
  }
  else{
    on.style.display = 'none';
    off.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

on.addEventListener('click', function(){
  toggle();
});

off.addEventListener('click', function(){
  toggle();
});
```

```css
#on {
  display: block;
}

#off {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="on">ON</button>
<button id="off">OFF</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this one worked for me. I appreciate the help, I am new to this and finding my way around